# How to write the symbol >

Tags: symbols

I had a look at the symbols list, and it is written that the input text ">" should be rendered as ">". In my document, however, it is rendered as "¿".

How do I write a normal ">"?

Comment: as Heiko says in his answer it is only an issue on OT1 encoding, but also, it is only an issue in _text_ > should almost always be in math mode where a `>` will always be typeset as >

Comment: I think the real question is in what context are you trying to "write a normal >"?  My guess is that you should be in math mode, or using a verbatim environment.

Comment: while the comments and answers are valid, this question would make much more sense if you showed the context in which you are using the symbol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very likely you are using the old `OT1` encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<Hello> \textless world\textgreater
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The example also shows how to typeset `<` and `>` by using `\textless` or `\textgreater`.

The issue is resolved with the `T1` font encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}% optional
\begin{document}
<Hello> \textless world\textgreater
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with T1 font encoding]